# how to create custom post type with dynamic category_name using shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I have created a custom post type with shortcode so I can add dynamic attributes from the shortcode

```php
function myCPT($query,  $attr) {
    $option = shortcode_atts(array('cat' => ''), $attr); 

    $query = new WP_query(array(
         'post_type' => 'myposttype',
         'category_name' =>   $option['cat']
    ));
    if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    $output .=  '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2><div>' . 
                '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div></div>' . 
                '<p>' . get_the_content() .  '</p><p>' . 
                '<a>DONATE NOW</a></p></div></div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'myCPT');
```

I'm calling it using `[myshortcode cat="mycategory"]`

I was expecting that `cat="mycategory"` should reflect on the `'category_name' => $option['cat']` from the custom query

But it is not working, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments for your `myCPT()` function are incorrect. Callbacks used for `add_shortcode()` received two arguments, in this order:

1. An array that contains the parameters used with the shortcode.
2. The that is between the opening and closing shortcode, if supported.

You code is assigning the attributes to `$query` (and then overwriting them), and trying to get the attributes from the shortcode content.

So you code needs to be:

```
function myCPT( $atts, $content ) {
    $option = shortcode_atts( array( 'cat' => '' ), $atts ); // This needs to be the same as the first argument. 

    $query = new WP_query( array(
        'post_type'     => 'myposttype',
        'category_name' => $option['cat']
    ) );

    // etc.
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'myCPT' );
```

Comment: thank you! works like a charm